# Static,total and velocity pressure at a point

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, aerodynamics, flow

I have a past exam question that I am stuck on.

> $200$m$^3/s$ of air is entering a shaft of $5m$ diameter, the density is $1.18$kg/m$^3$, and I have shock loss of factor $X=.5$

I want static, total and velocity pressure at the starting point.

Now I know that Shock loss is $\dfrac{X\rho v_1^2}{2}=\dfrac{.5\times1.18\times v_1^2}{2}$

and $v_1=\dfrac{200}{2.5^2 \pi}=10.186$

So Shock loss is $
\dfrac{.5\times1.18\times 10.186^2}{2}=30.608$

and Velocity pressure $=\dfrac{\rho v_1^2}{2}=61.215$

So I have VP and I  want Total and static pressure, but I have no idea  how to do this, any ideas would be lovely!

Comment: Are you given any information about static or total temperature?

Comment: The problem is, without the upstream temperature, the thermodynamic state of the flow is not defined. From what I can see, you need more information about the upstream conditions to be able to calculate the static and stagnation pressures.

Comment: Tip: Don't ever put any numbers in, until your very last line.

Comment: @Bryson: The density is given, along with the volume. The area of the shaft entrance is given, so the velocity can be determined. Isn't that enough to determine pressures?

Comment: @Mike Dunlavey I could have any combination of pressures and temperatures with the same exact velocity. But who knows, maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Maybe you can look at what upstream Mach number provides a shock loss of exactly 0.5. Considering that total pressure losses increase with Mach number, there should be only one upstream Mach that gives p02/p01 = 0.5 exactly (I think it's about 2.5 Mach)